# How to add json data to geojson map, without going 'back' to shape files?

Tags: json, r, geojson

I'm trying to add data in json format to a geojson file. I realise that one way of doing this, is to  transform the geojson file into a shape file, the data in an R object, and merge the two, as attempted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181339/r-geojson-and-leaflet). However, I was wondering whether this is possible without switching 'back' to a shape file. Here's the code to obtain the geojson file and data file:

```
library(leafletR)
library(jsonlite)

# obtaining map
  download.file("http://node-128.dev.socialhistoryservices.org/api/maps?year=1937",
                     destfile = paste0("testmap", ".json"))
  map <- leaflet("./testmap.json")
  map # displays map in browser

# obtaining data
  testdata <- 
  fromJSON("http://node-128.dev.socialhistoryservices.org/api/data?code=TXCU")
```

Note: the 'key' in both files is 'amsterdam_code'

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using node.js try [extend-geojson-properties](https://www.npmjs.org/package/extend-geojson-properties) and if want to use on client side download index.js file from [github project](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/extend-geojson-properties). See how to use in README of the project.

You can convert topojson to geojson features using [topojson api](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference). Then create a join map between geojson and json with common id.